# Get Interval Percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2014

Please consider this Table:

```
FileName            FileSize
----------------------------
 1                   33
 2                   198
 3                   10
 4                   127
 5                   85
 6                   23
 7                   105
 8                   158
 9                   78
 10                  90
```

and I want to create such this result:

```
FileSize             Percentage
--------------------------------
1-50                    30%
50-150                  50%
150-200                 20%
```

How I can `group by` and create percentage based on intervals?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a query without bounds table you can create a table inline using VALUES constructor like below

```
select DISTINCT
CAST(I.LowNumber as VARCHAR) + ' - '+  CAST(I.HighNumber as VARCHAR) as FileSize,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY lowNumber,HighNumber ORDER By lowNumber) * 100.00 /COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as percentage
from TblFile F
join (values (1, 50),(50, 150),(150, 200)) as I(LowNumber, highNumber)
on F.FileSize >=I.LowNumber and F.FileSize<I.HighNumber
Order By I.LowNumber
```

Your query should look like

```
select DISTINCT
CAST(I.LowNumber as VARCHAR) + ' - '+  CAST(I.HighNumber as VARCHAR) as FileSize,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY lowNumber,HighNumber ORDER By lowNumber) * 100.00 /COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as percentage
from TblFile F
join TblInterval I 
on F.FileSize >=I.LowNumber and F.FileSize<I.HighNumber
```

**Explanation:**

Ideally you should leverage set based approach and store the range values in a table. This allows for faster processing and also allows you a single place to limits externally and not in the procedure. This is also in line with Dependency injection principle.

For inline anonymous tables use VALUES constructor. More on this at [this msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

**[image: Output image reference:]**

PS: Insert scripts for table

```
--create table tblInterval (LowNumber Int, HighNumber Int)
--insert into tblInterval values
--(1,50),(50,150),(150,200)

create table tblFile (fileName int,fileSize int)
insert into tblFile values
( 1 ,33)
,( 2 ,198 )
,( 3 ,10  )
,( 4 ,127 )
,( 5 ,85  )
,( 6 ,23  )
,( 7 ,105 )
,( 8 ,158 )
,( 9 ,78  )
,( 10,90  )
```

Assuming you have a table like below

```
TblInterval

LowNumber HighNumber
  1        50
 50       150
150       200
```

Comment: Good work but I don't want to have a table for bounds. Can you re write your good query without bounds table?

Comment: That Works Thanks

Comment: @Arian you can use order by statement in this answer?

Comment: @Arian, Clearly the answer in the screenshot is not ordered

Comment: @Pream Isn't that a trivial thing to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statement to make the file size range then get percentage by the count like this

```
select a.range as FileSize, (Count(*)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From MyTable)) as Percentage
from (
select case  
when FileSize between 1 and 50 then '1-50'
when FileSize between 50 and 150 then '50-150'
when FileSize between 150 and 200 then '150-200' end as range
from MyTable) a
group by a.range
```

Comment: Great That works but result is not sorted and `order by FileSize` did not work. How I can sort it too...

Comment: all i can think of is add "1)1-50 , 2)50-150" instead of "1-50 , 50-150" as they are strings and not numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(
FILENAME   INT,         FILESIZE INT
)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES
(1,33),
(2,198),
(3,10),
(4,127),
(5,85),
(6,23),
(7,105),
(8,158),
(9,78),
(10,90)

SELECT RANGE,COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #A)    AS PERCENTAGE
FROM ( 
SELECT *,CASE  
WHEN FILESIZE BETWEEN 1 AND 50 THEN '1-50'
WHEN FILESIZE BETWEEN 50 AND 150 THEN '50-150'
WHEN FILESIZE BETWEEN 150 AND 200 THEN '150-200' END AS RANGE
FROM #A) A
GROUP BY A.RANGE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN RANGE = '1-50' THEN 1 
              WHEN RANGE ='50-150' THEN 2
              WHEN RANGE ='150-200' THEN 3
                                    END
```

output

```
RANGE   PERCENTAGE
1-50    30
50-150  50
150-200 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVG together with partition by:

```
select distinct 
case  
when FileSize between 1 and 50 then '1-50'
when FileSize between 50 and 150 then '50-150'
when FileSize between 150 and 200 then '150-200' end as range
, avg(FileSize) OVER (PARTITION BY (select 
                                    case when filesize between 0 and 50 then 1 
                                    when filesize between 50 and 150 then 2
                                    when filesize between 150 and 200 then 3
                                    end)) as percentage
from mytable
```

Comment: Sorry it did not generate my desire result